# Get data from Spinner and convert to number - Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, numbers, spinner, calculator

I am writing a simple android application in Kotlin.
Functionality is the following:
The user enters information and the program calculates his salary.
Stuck on getting information from the spinner. Let's say there are 12 months, the user selects January from the Spinner list, and I need to convert his choice to the number 31(quantity of days) then use this data for the calculator.

1st question is how to create "When" statement for all 12 months and convert chosen data to Numbers.

2st question how to use/get this numbers in my fun calculateSalary()

MainActivity:

```
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        binding.calculateButton.setOnClickListener { calculateSalary() }

        binding.baseSalaryEditText.setOnKeyListener { view, keyCode, _ ->
            handleKeyEvent(
                view,
                keyCode
            )
        }
        val spinner: Spinner = findViewById(R.id.month)


// Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
        ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this,
            R.array.month_array,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item
        ).also { adapter ->
            // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
            // Apply the adapter to the spinner
            spinner.adapter = adapter

        }
    }
        abstract class SpinnerActivity : Activity(), AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

            override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>, view: View?, pos: Int, id: Long) {
                // An item was selected. You can retrieve the selected item using
                // parent.getItemAtPosition(pos)

            }

                override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>) {
                    // Another interface callback
                }



}

     private fun calculateSalary() {
        val stringInTextField = binding.baseSalaryEditText.text.toString()
        val base = stringInTextField.toDoubleOrNull()
        if (base == null || base == 0.0) {
            displaySalary(0.0)
            return
        }
        val stringInTextField2 = binding.workingDaysEditText.text.toString()
        val workingDays = stringInTextField2.toDoubleOrNull()
        if (workingDays == null || workingDays == 0.0) {
            displaySalary(0.0)
            return
        }


        // here will be formula  = base / monthDays * workingDays
        var salary = base
        displaySalary(salary)

    }

    private fun displaySalary(salary: Double) {
        val formattedTip = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(salary)
        binding.totalResult.text = getString(R.string.salary_amount, formattedTip)
    }

    private fun handleKeyEvent(view: View, keyCode: Int): Boolean {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
            // Hide the keyboard
            val inputMethodManager =
                getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
            inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, 0)
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So What you will do is link each of the 12 entries in your spinner with an `int` number that will reference the days. Make a list with 12 entries each with the amount of days for the month. Then with the following code:

```
   var months: List =  arrayOf("30", "28", "31", "30", "30", "31")
       var days: Int  = 0 //this will be the month picked converted into days

        spinnerMonth.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{
            override fun onItemSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?, p1: View?, p2: Int, p3: Long) {
             

                days = months[p2].toInt() //p2 is the position selected in the spinner

                calculateSalary(days)
            }
            override fun onNothingSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?) {
            }
              
        }
```

You should now be able to get the amount of days and have it sent to you function
through - `calculateSalary(days)`